# Register multi-touch as a single touch?

Tags: ios, ipados

Is there a way to register multi-touch as a single touch? Say if I use three fingers to tap a large button, can it be registered as simply one tap of the button? -- the current default appears to treat it as a multi-touch, and as a result ignores the button-pressing altogether. Similarly, if I use my palm to tap a large button, the button isn't pressed either.

I noticed in iphone Accessibility Settings -> Touch Accommodations, one could set "Ignore Repeat" and "Use Initial Touch Location" for tap assistance. Of course, if those are turned on, it affects the entire phone instead of just one app. But would that be the direction to approach this problem?

BTW I don't actually need multi-touch in my app. So if turning off multi-touch can be more simply done on the whole-app level instead of button-by-button, it would suit this case very well.

Comment: Hmmm... quick test... 200x200 point button... `touchUpInside` target is triggered whether I tap with one, two or three fingers. If I touch down *outside* the button with one finger, keep it down, and then tap the button with a second finger, I still get the `touchUpInside` triggered. Are you sure that's not the behavior you're getting?

Comment: Thanks you @DonMag! Right, so I've been using Capacitor to develop ios apps. I found out that the reason is that I was using onClick events to trigger the button press, and -- just like what you've hinted with your test, what mattered was the locations of the "down" event and "up" event -- multi-touch must have resulted in them being different, which messed up "onClick". I thought I'd have to change how touch is processed in the Swift code; but with that discovery, I changed "onClick" to "onTouchStart" in the javascript, and three-finger taps of large buttons now work!

Comment: Hmmm... yeah... it would have been helpful if you explained in your original question that you are using some other code (which is obviously managing the touches).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DonMag for providing a hint.

So, if yours is an ios app from Capacitor, here is how to change your javascript code:

- Change your button onClick events into "onTouchStart"
- Use a state variable to keep track of whether "onTouchStart" is triggered and the resulting logic is executing. During that execution, prevent more touch events to have further effect on the button. This is to prevent the button from being pressed in quick succession by multiple touches that come from, say, your three-finger tap or palm tap. Only after the execution is finished do you revert the state variable back to the original value, so that the button is ready to be pressed again.

If there is an answer that's more suitable for the native Swift bundle I'll accept that as the answer. The above is just to help anyone who may encounter the same problem as mine.